# Is there a way to check if properties of an Object have values or not?

Tags: java, loops, class

I have an object which is filled with data from the database. Now I would like to know or I have to know which properties of this object have values in them or not.

**My Entity Class:**

```
public class PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity {
@Expose
private Long purchasingDeadlineValuesId;
@Expose private Long purchasingDeadlineId;
@Expose private Long mandantKagId;
@Expose private double zero;
@Expose private double one;
@Expose private double two;
@Expose private double three;
@Expose private double four;
@Expose private double five;
@Expose private double six;
@Expose private double seven;
@Expose private double eight;
@Expose private double nine;
@Expose private double ten;
@Expose private double eleven;
@Expose private double twelve;
@Expose private double thirteen;
private Timestamp dateCreated;
private Timestamp dateUpdated;

//getter & Setter..and so
```

I thought about taking the declared fields from the class and comparing them with the properties of the object. But how can I get any further.

**This is my attempt where I do not get ahead:**

```
    protected HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Double>> extractKagAndPurchasingDeadlines() {
    Field[] fields = PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.class.getDeclaredFields();

    for (MandantKagAccountEntity mandantKagAccountEntity : m_k_a_E) {
        PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity = mandantKagAccountEntity.getPurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getType().equals(double.class)) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i need to now if the value of the double Fields in the PurchasingDeadline Object are greater than 0.0. But they can also be null.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: You need to define what it means to have a value or rather what "no value" means. Is it 0.0 or Double.MIN_VALUE or something else that means "no value"

Comment: Changed my Question. Thanks

Comment: So with no value, i mean the propertie should be greater than 0.0. But they could be null

Comment: `double` can't be null since it is a primitive type but `Double` can be null since it is a class.

Comment: yeahr right. But how can i check if the properties of the Object are grater than 0.0?

Comment: That's a different question. 0 is a value. It might have resulted from default initialization, or it might have been put there from the database, or from a calculation. There is no decision procedure that can tell you that 0 isn't a value. The fact is that all primitive fields will have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, this is what you want:

```java
for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getType().equals(double.class)) {
        final double value = (double) field.get(purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity);
        if (value > 0.0) {
            // do whatever you want with `value`
        }
    }
}
```

And this is full working example:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {

        final PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity = new PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity();
        purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.setDeadlineId(2L);
        purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.setZero(0.0);
        purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.setOne(2.0);

        Field[] fields = PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getType().equals(double.class)) {
                final double value = (double) field.get(purchasingDeadlineValuesEntity);
                if (value > 0.0) {
                    System.out.println("field name = " + field.getName());
                    System.out.println("field value = " + value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class PurchasingDeadlineValuesEntity {
        private Long deadlineId;

        private double zero;

        private double one;

        private double two;

        public Long getDeadlineId() {
            return deadlineId;
        }

        public void setDeadlineId(Long deadlineId) {
            this.deadlineId = deadlineId;
        }

        public double getZero() {
            return zero;
        }

        public void setZero(double zero) {
            this.zero = zero;
        }

        public double getOne() {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(double one) {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public double getTwo() {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(double two) {
            this.two = two;
        }
    }
}
```